# JQuery Select2 plugin suggestions in plain text and not html formatted

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am having a weird issue on jQuery select2 (bootstrap) plugin. Everything works fine but the suggestions HTML is displaying as is (in plain text). The code I am implementing is as follows:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $ajax = $(".js-example-data-ajax");
    $ajax.select2({
        ajax: {
            url: "...",
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    q: params.term, // search term
                    page: params.page
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data, params) {
                params.page = params.page || 1;
                return {
                    results: data,
                    pagination: {
                        more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
                    }
                };
            },
            cache: true,

        },
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        templateResult: function (repo) {
            if (repo.loading){
                return repo.text;
            }

            var markup = '<div class="col-md-12">' + repo.name + '</div>';
            return markup;
        },
        templateSelection: function (repo) {
            return repo.name || repo.text;
        }
    });
});
        </script>
```

The response is "< div class="col-md-12">Name< / div> "
I am using version Select2 4.0.1 on JQuery 1.11.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to be returning HTML in your templates, you need to return a jQuery object.

```
templateResult: function (repo) {
    if (repo.loading){
        return repo.text;
    }

    var markup = $('<div class="col-md-12">' + repo.name + '</div>');
    return markup;
},
```

Comment: Thank a lot Kevin, that did it!